# How to overcome TUN.KO driver issue in Android for VPN

Tags: android, driver, vpn, tun

How to overcome "Tun.ko" driver issue in few android devices because of which VPN never connects. Is there any way to identify the presence of "Tun.ko" driver and disable VPN or if possible to install driver without rooting?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a large repository of tun modules here, with an installer for them: http://droidvpn.com/tun-repository.php